# Windows Search Function does not find existing folders (and files)

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I am trying to find some folders using the search function in Windows 10. But it seemingly does not find folders even though they are definitely there. Suggestions are very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the location you are searching is in the Index Locations to be searched. If not there, add the location using the Modify button and rebuild the index.

[image: Index Options]

2. Make sure you are not trying to index Program Files and Windows. Those are secured folders and indexing these does not work .
3. If the location in not indexed and you wish to find something, open Windows File Explorer, navigate to the top location of the file / folder you wish to find and search using the top right search icon. That is very handy.